# Change embed source class dynamically

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript, flex3

im working on a Flex application and i need to update a button icon source dynamically, but, its not enough for me by changing the icon attribute to another Class variable on runtime, i need to explicitly change the Class source to another. I google my  doubt but has no the answer yet.

I want something like the following:
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Flex/Graphics/ChangeImagesourceinbuttonaction.htm

But i need it to do somethig like this instead:

```
[Embed(source="sun.jpg")]
[Bindable]
private var dayAsset:Class;

private function init(  ):void {
    dayImage.source = dayAsset;
}

private function showMoon(  ):void {
    dayAsset.source = "moon.jpg";
}

private function showSun(  ):void {
    dayAsset.source = "sun.jpg";
}
```

I have tried the previous code without success.

Why do i need to update the "dayImage" image source this way?? Because i have the image referenced on more than one location and i need to update it all on an event triggered

Any solution :P or comments will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks. have a nice night.

Comment: I'm not following.  If you want to update dayImage.source why can't you just do 'dayImage.source = newValue'?  If you're asking to change the enbed, then you cannot.  Embeds are performed compile time and you can't change them at compile time.

Comment: Yeah, I did not knew that I was not able to change the embed, but the thing was that I had more than one image referring that embed, so, if I tried something like: 'dayImage.source = newValue', I was going to be forced to do it for all that images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF I understand the question; then the answer is that you cannot change embeds at runtime.  They are performed at compile time; and made part of your compiled SWF.

You most likely want to do an approach like this:

```
// embed both images
[Embed(source="sun.jpg")]
[Bindable]
private var dayAssetSun:Class;

[Embed(source="moon.jpg")]
[Bindable]
private var dayAssetMoon:Class;

// us a variable to store the reference to the image you want to see
private var currentDayAsset :Class;

// set the current asset
private function init(  ):void {
    dayImage.source = currentDayAsset;
}

// these methods change the currentDayAsset variable; but do not affect the embeds
private function showMoon(  ):void {
    currentDayAsset =  dayAssetMoon;
}

private function showSun(  ):void {
    currentDayAsset =  dayAssetSun;
}
```

Comment: Ok man, that's the functionality i want, i didnt knew embeds cannot be assigned on runtime. Thanks so much.

Comment: I have to make a comment about the answer, it's all correct except that the bindable tag has to be applied to the "dayAssetMoon" variable instead. This is because the "currentDayAsset" is the variable that will be referenced as source on all the images, so, it is the one that needs to be bindable.

Comment: @HugoAllexisCardona Whether currentDayAsset needs to be Bindable or not really depends how you're using it; which isn't something covered in your question (or my answer).  But, if you're using it in MXML as the source to something like an Image tag; then yes you'll need to make 'currentDayAsset' bindable.

Comment: Exactly man, I'm using that source for multiple images instantiated by MXML. It works pretty good. Thanks for replying